# problem in welding vertices, a beginner

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I try to weld my vertices so its connected one by one but you can see here on the image I specified it doesn't turns out to what I wanted it to be, is there any solution for this type of problem?

[image]

Comment: could you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve (e.g. sample images)? Do you want all the point to be merged into one?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to join two UV islands together? If that is the case use the **Stitch** option instead of Weld.   ( RMB > Stitch )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've chosen the wrong option from the *Merge* menu?

Make sure, of the selected vertices, the ones you want to be merged are closer to one another than to any others, and *Merge > By Distance*

[image]

Or, if that's too fiddly, (and you want the merged loop to be centered to the ones above and below) select the edge-loops you want to be merged, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> *Edge Menu > Bridge Edge Loops*, with '*Merge*' checked in its options.

Comment: thank you for helping me out, it worked!